# Mongodb aggregate $size not returning results?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I have data like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "60ccb13a21d65f0c7c4c0690",
    "username": "testuser",
    "friendRequests": [
      {
        "_id": "60ccb13a21d65f0c7c4c0690",
        
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And code like this:

```
router.use(async function(req, res, next){

    try {
        res.locals.fr = await User.aggregate([
            {$match:{username: "testuser"}},    
            {$project: {
                frCount: {
                  $size: "$friendRequests"
                }
              }}]),
        res.locals.login = req.isAuthenticated();
        res.locals.newProfile = req.user;
        next();
    }
    catch {
        res.locals.login = req.isAuthenticated();
        res.locals.newProfile = req.user;
        next();
    }

});
```

Shouldnt it return this?

```
[
  {
    "frCount": 1,
    "_id": ObjectId("60ccb13a21d65f0c7c4c0690")
  }
]
```

Then if I put this in EJS:

```
<p>requests: <%= fr.frCount %></p>
```

Shouldn't it return 1? However, it returns nothing and I'm not sure why.

Comment: it IS returning proper response. https://mongoplayground.net/p/dCVRGl2EXxP

Comment: Then I don't understand, if I put this in ejs: Friend requests: <%= FR.frCount %>, it doesn't return anything

Comment: can you post the relevant part of the code as well in the question. otherwise it's impossible to know what is wrong

Comment: Yes sorry, I updated it with the full code and the ejs code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are getting returned is not an Object. it's an array: https://mongoplayground.net/p/dCVRGl2EXxP

```
[
  {
    "_id": "60ccb13a21d65f0c7c4c0690",
    "frCount": 2
  }
]
```

So, you need to do `fr[0].frCount` to get the value.